# How do you refresh a page or certain content for a number of times and then stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

I have a HTML page which has CSS animations and I wanted to know if there is a way where I wanted the page to reload 3 times and then stop it. Also when reloading it 3 times, for each time I want it to have a delay so for example the first time when my page loads it will play the animations and then after all the animations have been played I want it to reload again so some kind of a delay function?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just have the CSS animation loop three times?

Comment: You can try setTimeout and at the same time set a cookie with the page reload count.

Comment: @JonathonBlok That would not work because I have several animations which are in different classes and also I am using animate.css by Daniel Eden. I do not know how to make it into one whole animation and then loop that if you get what I am trying to say?

Comment: @Swaprks Is it possible to give me an example please?

Comment: @Dorvalla well I tried <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="20"> but that keeps reloading the page every 20 seconds.... Then I tried using this -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;  but because I have many other animations it treats one animation as an individual animation when I want it to be treated as a whole.

Comment: Sounds like a usability wise nightmare that page

Answer (score 2):

Add this on page load.

```
<script>   

    var timeinmilliseconds = 3000;
    var reloadCnt = window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter") ? parseInt(window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter")) + 1 : 1;

    window.sessionStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", reloadCnt )
    console.log(reloadCnt);
    if ( reloadCnt <= 3 )
      setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(true) }, timeinmilliseconds);
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps. This is pure javascript, just add it to your page and let me know. Here is the link [http://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/pyecrtku/)

Comment: I'd use [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of a cookie. Info doesn't need to be send to the server.

Comment: @Swaprks Can I copy and paste this code into the Html and will it make it work or do I need to change anything?

Comment: @ViratKohli if you have jquery library included and if you want the page to reload after 3sec, you ca add this to the script tags and it will work

Comment: @Swaprks Is this Correct?                                                                                <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> var timeinmilliseconds = 3000;
var reloadCnt = $.cookie("example") ? $.cookie("example") + 1 : 1;
$.cookie("reloadCounter", reloadCnt );

if ( reloadCnt <= 3 )
  setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(true) }, timeinmilliseconds);</script>

Comment: No. I think you are new to this.

Comment: @Swaprks yes lol Could you please help me out and guide me? Thank you :)

Comment: @Swaprks Hey I have another question, I tried to upload this in Double click studio but it doesn't allow me to use that code so is there any other way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: @ViratKohli what is double click studio?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can easily do it.

```js
const wait = (time) =>
    new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });

const reload = async (times = 5, delay = 1000) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("count") === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("count", 0);
    }

    let count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));
    if (count > times - 1) {
        console.log("stopped refreshing...");
        return;
    }
    count++;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);

    await wait(delay);
    window.location.reload();
};

reload();
```

Make sure to clear `count` value from your local storage after testing this initially.